# SQL Query to Count total entries by Month/Year

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datatable, group-by

I am trying to count the total number of entries in my SQL table for each month.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`ID` int, `date` date, `job` varchar)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`ID`, `date`, `job`)
VALUES
    (1, '2019-01-01', job A),
    (2, '2019-01-03', job B),
    (3, '2019-02-02', job C),
    (4, '2019-04-05', job D),
    (5, '2019-05-03', job E),
    (6, '2019-07-07', job F)
;

Select
DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y') MontnameYear,
COUNT(job) counter
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y')
ORDER by mdate;
```

I have tried various different variations of the above but nothing that gets me a count for each month. I have a feeling that I am missing something obvious but cant see it :-(

Any help would be great

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  Also, "datatable" is not a SQL database, so it is unclear what kind of code you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff GMB has given me the answer I need, thanks :-). I am populating a Datatable from an SQL database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query looks fine, apart from the `group by` clause, that refers to a column alias that does not exist in the query (that's a syntax error).

Consider:

```
Select
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y') MontnameYear,
    COUNT(*) counter
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%M %Y')
ORDER by MIN(`date`)
```

**[Demo on DB FIddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=306cfbf0f25258fdb566181cc7c22c9a)**:

```
MontnameYear  | counter
:------------ | ------:
January 2019  |       2
February 2019 |       1
April 2019    |       1
May 2019      |       1
July 2019     |       1
```

Side notes: your sample script has flaws:

- it is mandatory to give a length to a `varchar` column (say, `varchar(10)`)
- strings such as `job A` must be surrounded with single quotes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried to run that I got an error - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=90a26dc08fba493d557961b8fe125c0d any thoughts?

Comment: @PaulMcF87: these problems come from your `create/insert` script. See my updated answer (and my db fiddle as well).

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Sorted :-)